# REST client - How to send data with PUT request?

Tags: rest

I've created a REST API using Codeigniter and I'm testing it with wiztools.org REST client https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

How can and should I send data for a PUT request? I've seen some PHP examples where JSON is sent in the headers but I'm not sure how to do this in the client I'm testing with or how to read this data from the request.

Comment: Are you asking about operating instructions for RESTClient?

Comment: What problems are you encountering?  Have you successfully done GET and POST requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cURL](http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/) to send PUT requests.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the exactly particular rest client you have mentioned above but with Rest Client in VS Code you can send the PUT request as follows:

Assuming that the api is http://localhost:3000/api/subject and it needs authorization token.

PUT http://localhost:3000/api/subject
Authorization: Basic 
Content-Type: application/json

{
"id": 1,
"name": "Data structures and algorithm"
}